# Problem with y-axis value limited to 1 using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axis

I'm making a categorical point plot using seaborn, and I have area values (km2) assigned to dates.

When I plot these dates, the y-axis is limited from 0 to 1, when I know there are several values higher than 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure


# Read in the backscatter csv file as a data frame
df_lakearea = pd.read_csv('lake_area.csv')

figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

# Control aesthetics 
sns.set()
sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={"grid.linewidth": 0.2, "lines.linewidth": 0.5}) # White grid background, width of grid  line and series line
sns.set_context(font_scale = 0.5) # Scale of font

# Use seaborn pointplot function to plot the lake area 
lakearea_plot = sns.pointplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(df_lakearea), color='maroon', linestyles=["-"], join="True", capsize=0.2)
# Use the pd.melt function to converts the wide-form data frame to long-form.

# Rotate the x axis labels so that they are readable
plt.setp(lakearea_plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=20)

params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }
plt.rcParams.update(params)

lakearea_plot.set(xlabel='', ylabel='Area $(km^2)$')
lakearea_plot.tick_params(labelsize=8) # Control the label size
```

I expect the results to look much like a normal time series plot, with values assigned to each date and the error bars reaching min and max points, just not with the max value being 1 on the y axis. The image below shows what I have and the y-axis max being 1.

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLyl.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The confidence interval does not include all points, but by default the range within which 95% of the points lie. That's somehow how errorbars are most often defined.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the CI, in this case, is actually a little bit different. Pls take a look of my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

First, when you plot a categorical pointplot in `seaborn`, your y-values (numerical values) are aggregated to the means based on each category. Let's use a seaborn's dataset to demonstrate.

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.pointplot(x='day', y='tip', data=df)
```

[image]

In this plot, you can see that `Thur` has a y-value of roughly 2.8, this is because the mean of the tips on Thur is 2.8-ish. We can verify this by:

```py
df.groupby('day').tip.mean()

[Out]:
day
Thur    2.771452
Fri     2.734737
Sat     2.993103
Sun     3.255132
Name: tip, dtype: float64
```

Second, you may have also noticed that Fri has a bigger confidence interval (CI) than other groups. In fact, the size of the CI in this kind of line plot represents your sample size rather than the data distribution. We can verify this by:

```py
df.day.value_counts()

[Out]:
df.day.value_counts()
Sat     87
Sun     76
Thur    62
Fri     19
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, we only have 19 observations associated with Fri in our dataset. Comparing with other groups, thus, we are "less confident" about our estimation (the mean). This is why it has a wider CI than other groups.

Here's another example:

```
sns.regplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=df)
```

[image]

You can tell that the CI is much wider around 50 because we only have a few data points there.

Thus, you should check if the mean of each group in your data is within your y-axis limit and if the CI represents the number of your data points in each group.

Comment: Pls leave a comment for the downvote so that I know what the problem is to improve the answer.